# Multiples angular-seed projects

Tags: angularjs, git

I just started to learn AngularJS, I finished [PhoneCat Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and now i'll try to start with my own personal project, as recomended in angularjs doc, i'll use  [angularseed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed). I've cloned it,and it create a local folder called angular-seed, but i have a question if i always use angular-seed project as skeleton, all my projects folders will be "angular-seed", and if i also checkd .git folder and configure file has url = to the original angular-seed link, so it will always be linked to original angular-seed project???

Comment: you may modify them manually..

Comment: thanks for answer Bohendra Nepal, and what about git integration, i don't want to commit to original angular seed project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below step to resolve issue

1) delete .git folder from you local folder called angular-seed.

2) right click on that folder and open git bash if you are not getting that option than manually go to that folder location

3) run command git-init now in you local folder called angular-seed again you can see .git folder but it will not point to original git repository

4) when you want to check in you changes in give your git repository url

to know more how to configure git refer below url:[git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/)

Comment: Thank you very much user27343 , it's what i was looking for.